# Permanent residency application with adverse travel history

Tags: canada, australia

I am a Sri Lankan and I intend to apply for a skilled immigrant permanent resident visa in either Canada or Australia. For these countries, most of my skills are adequate to apply, but my recent travel has brought a new complication.

I recently travelled to Russia for my sibling's convocation, but I was removed from the port without any reason given, after the interview with the Immigration officer. They said they have the right to withhold the reason. There is a cancelled stamp on my Russian visa, and my passport was not returned to me until I reached my country.

I have to include this information in my Canada application form in the travel history. Will this incident count against me?

Comment: That's up to Canada to decide. You still have to tell the truth.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is almost certainly *yes, but not much.*

When wealthy nations decide which immigrants they are going to accept, they look for things like age, education, economic success, and **respect for laws and regulations.** People who have broken the law *elsewhere* might be more likely to do so in their new home as well. People who are generally law-abiding and orderly might be more likely to behave that way in their new home.

Canada and Australia are not especially fond of Russia these days, so the bad opinion of a Russian official will carry less weight than a similar event in the US or UK. But lying about it *to the Canadians or Australians* would probaby wreck your chances if they find out.